# Regex for all uppercase words until lowercases

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence like:

```
Name: JOHN J. SMITH Sometag:
```

How would I grab the `JOHN J SMITH` part?

`Sometag` is not always the same so it would be more like get all all-capitalized words until one that is not.

UPDATE

`"[A-Z. ]*"` returns JOHN J. SMITH S
`"[A-Z. ]*\b"` returns nothing as well as
`"\b[A-Z. ]*\b"`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Neal: I once sent a coworker a bulleted list of things they were doing wrong. I now regret that decision. The answer is nothing. I have rarely used Regex so I DONT KNOW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[A-Z. ]*\b
```

Let me know how it goes

You can be be more complete with this one

```
[\p{Lu}\p{M}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}]*\b
```

But its a mouthful

```
Match a single character present in the list below «[\p{Lu}\p{M}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{P}\p{S}]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   A character with the Unicode property “uppercase letter” (an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant) «\p{Lu}»
   A character with the Unicode property “mark” (a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)) «\p{M}»
   A character with the Unicode property “separator” (any kind of whitespace or invisible separator) «\p{Z}»
   A character with the Unicode property “number” (any kind of numeric character in any script) «\p{N}»
   A character with the Unicode property “punctuation” (any kind of punctuation character) «\p{P}»
   A character with the Unicode property “symbol” (math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc.) «\p{S}»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```

Or shorter

```
\P{Ll}*\b
```

**Update 1**

After your edit I would use this

```
Name: (\P{Ll}*)[ ]
```

The desired match will be in group 1. Note that I added a [ ] in the end so to signal a single space. You can convert this character class to a space if you want.

In C# this becomes

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"Name: (\p{Ll}*)[ ]");
    resultString = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups[1].Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: @TomFobear If you present the regex of update 1 the input "Name: JOHN J. SMITH Sometag:" It will have "JOHN J. SMITH" in group 1. This is what you needed no?

Answer (score 0):

couldn't use a negative look ahead and find the uppercases not followed by a lowercase?

(([A-Z. ])(?![a-z:]))+

`String caps=Regex.Match("Name: JOHN J. SMITH Sometag: ","(([A-Z. ])(?![a-z:]))+").ToString()`